# Does Visual Studio 2010 benefit from quad core vs dual core machines? Is compilation multithreaded?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows XP machine with a dual core 3.6G CPU and 4megs. I am not very happy with the performance. I was wondering if compilation in VS 2010 is multithreaded and does VS 2010 benefit from switching from dual to quad core machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 written to use multi cores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814015/was-visual-studio-2008-or-2010-written-to-use-multi-cores)

Answer (score 4):

What language are you working in? The native C++ compiler will spawn off multiple processes when you build. In VS 2008 it was one project per core; now it will use multiple cores even if you have only one (presumably huge) project. I don't think managed code does.

A helpful blog entry on what hardware will be useful with VS 2010 is http://blogs.msdn.com/ddperf/archive/2008/12/23/visual-studio-2010-hardware-requirements.aspx for more.

Comment: VS 2008 already supported the same type of multi-core compilation, but wasn't enabled by default. You needed to add the /MP switch. Typical speedup from this on a dual core machine is around 30%. I'd also be curious how well it scales with more cores.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably get a bigger speed up from changing your hard disk (i.e., to SSD) and installing VS and putting your projects on that disk. It'll speed up the Intellisense cache and what-not. If you're on XP rather than Vista or Windows 7 too, the shell on VS2010 was rewritten to use WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) and WPF is not optimised for XP; it will run slower.

Comment: Many SSD-s don't like small files, and frequent writes will also degrade their lifetime. 10k hard drives are pretty expensive, and you can get similar performance by short stroking a 7200 rpm drive (assuming the 10k drive is not short stroken, because it's too small for that to be practical).

Comment: People are still short-stroking drives in the SSD era? Also, SSD cope with small files just fine, far better than a mechanical drive. Additionally, you can put a swap file on an SSD and it won't wear out for many, many years. Frequent writes are inconsequential with the wear leveling.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation of large projects tends to be very disk-intensive. Getting a faster disk will speed up the build process.

Comment: Placing intermediate files on a ramdisk can help a lot.

Comment: Look above on my reply - put WHOLE project on RamDisk

Answer (score -1):

Skip SSD and buy more RAM and put all your projects on RamDisk like SoftPerfect RAMDisk