# Running Visual Studio in multiple cores

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, multicore

I'm coding in Visual Studio 2012 and my processor has 4 cores.

Sometimes Visual Studio freezes and I take a look at Task manager, and `devenv.exe` process is 25% at top (one core).

I'm not sure if it's because I have too many plugins enabled, large project or just my current config isn't bearing Visual Studio with all applications opened. (Windows 7 / AMD X4 640 w/ Chrome, MSSMS, Skype, Outlook...). But, I would like to run Visual Studio with other cores to deal with it..

**Is there a way to run Visual Studio using all cores while I'm working in?**

(Note that I'm not asking for multi-core builds - as many questions around).

Comment: Just a shoot from the hip - high CPU usage might be just sign that too many IO operations are waiting to be finished; if you want to improve VS studio performance, get a SSD disk. Also have you tried starting vs without plugins (/SafeMode) ?

Comment: You can try this
http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/ramdisk-for-fast-visual-studio-solution-compile/

Comment: I am only on a dual core but I see the same thing.  Some times Visual Studio maxes out one CPU.   I reboot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was Visual Studio 2008, 2010 or 2012 (v11) written to use multi cores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814015/was-visual-studio-2008-2010-or-2012-v11-written-to-use-multi-cores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that sounds like `devenv.exe` is maxing out one of your cores. It's very hard to say what the cause of your specific problem is, but if like you said you do have numerous plugins running, disabling them and then reenabling them one at a time would no doubt help find out if they are the cause or not.

As for your main question, one would think that the designers of Visual Studio did their best to take full advantage of available CPU resources and it is unlikely that there is a separate setting to enable some kind of special multicore mode.

Comment: I am not really sure this is correct. Many times I noticed one (out of four) CPU getting maxed up keeping other 3 free. So there should be some setting about core numbers.

Comment: When I disabled Resharper I've got improvement. Still freezing sometimes, but less than before.

Comment: If you find resharper using a lot, then turn off the Code Analysis, leaving you still being able to use the Productivity elements of it.   Resharper | Manage Options | Code Inspection - Settings.  Untick Enable Code Analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Check the CPU affinity in the Task Manager. It might be set to only one core.